# What is phonegap cli version (refering to supported OS version)?

Tags: phonegap

Could not find a clear explanation of my question.

So we have a table of currenlty "supported versions":

```
phonegap-version    Android Phonegap Version    iOS Phonegap Version
cli-8.0.0   7.0.0   4.5.4
cli-7.1.0   6.3.0   4.5.4
cli-7.0.1   6.2.3   4.4.0
cli-6.5.0   6.1.2   4.3.1
```

If I use for the app build say `cli-8.0.0`, does it mean that devices with `Android` below `7.0.0` will not be supported and app won't work on them?

If so what are the reason to use higher cli-versions, if we usually want to have max compatibility with the user devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using Cordova Android 7.1.4 version. I have tested that though it's targeted on Android API level 27 (8.1 Oreo), it works on Android 7.0 Nougat. But doesn't work on 6.0 or anything below. Then I have reduced the Cordova Android version and it started working on older and older Android versions. But there is no consistency on what is supported below the targeted version.

While higher CLI versions provide more functionality, in order to support older Android versions, you have to use older Cordova versions it seems.

Refer the release notes to see what never versions of Cordova offer than the old,

[Cordova release notes](https://github.com/apache/cordova-cli/blob/master/RELEASENOTES.md)

You can use higher CLI versions for newer features, stabilty and security at the compromise of maximum device compatibility.